# Is there an FAA-rated airplane safety harness?

Tags: air-travel, safety, children, child-safety-seats

Which safety harness is FAA rated?
I have looked at a few, but am unclear which ones are FAA rated and what the rating is.

Comment: welcome to [travel.SX](http://travel.stackexchange.com)! please try to be more specific in what your needs are - stating e.g. that you're looking for a harness to keep a child safe, plus the age of the child, etc

Answer (score 3):

The ['Child Safety' page](http://www.faa.gov/passengers/fly_children/) has some information on this. Mostly it says that child safety restraint systems (CRS) get approved for traffic and/or airline use by the [National Highway Traffic Safety Administration](http://www.nhtsa.gov/), but that FAA does not control all of the approvals. And stresses to check that the CRS has the label:

> This restraint is certified for use in motor vehicles and aircraft

It further uses four categories based on the weight of the child:

> - Less than 20 pounds: Rear-facing CRS
> - 20 to 40 pounds: Forward-facing CRS
> - 22 to 44 pounds: [CARES child safety device](http://kidsflysafe.com/cares-overview/)
> - More than 40 pounds: Airplane seat belt

With the CARES device being that described in @Darren's answer and by the FAA:

> The CARES Child Safety Device is the only FAA-approved harness-type
>   restraint for children weighing between 22 and 44 pounds. This type of
>   device provides an alternative to using a hard-backed seat and is
>   approved only for use on aircraft. The CARES Child Safety Device is
>   not approved for use in motor vehicles. Learn more about CARES.

And if you're getting one of them, you should check:

> If you're using a CARES child safety device, make sure it has "FAA
>   Approved in Accordance with 14 CFR 21.8(d), Approved for Aircraft Use
>   Only" or "FAA Approved in Accordance with 14 CFR 21.305(d), Amd 21.50
>   6-9-1980, Approved for Aircraft Use Only" on it.

Answer (score 1):

> CARES Child Aviation Restraint System is designed specifically for
>   aviation use for children age 1 and older who weigh between 22 and 44
>   pounds. These youngsters are old enough to be in their own seats, but
>   are too small for the seat belt alone to protect them and provide the
>   safety they require during airplane travel. Their bodies cannot
>   withstand the jolts that are common in routine air travel, much less
>   emergency situations, and they flail forward or slide beneath the seat
>   belt if they are not held securely in place.
>
> CARES is the first and only harness type Aviation Child Safety Device
>   to be certified by the Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) as an
>   alternative to a car seat.

http://kidsflysafe.com/cares-overview/

Comment: you might want to note that your whole answer is a direct citation from that website - e.g. using the comment button in the editor while having your answer (or a single paragraph) selected.